# How to remove interaction in openlayers?

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

Heres my gist.
On componentWillUnmount, I try to remove an interaction, but it doesnt remove
https://gist.github.com/columnistdc/b5a29b8996d1152f57c8dc1cd6caaf61

Comment: This is a very unclear question. The gist has gone, so could you try adding a code snippet to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Gist is deleted.
If you cannot remove an interaction through `map.removeInteraction(interaction)`, you can try `map.getInteractions().pop()`
Very strange decision

Comment: That answer solved my problem a few weeks ago. Now I need a more robust solution. I need to remove specific interactions as the user makes selection from a list. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe you can use map.getInteractions(), then filter those interactions by some values...
I'm not sure, but i saw this phrase in docs:
`getInteractions()
Get the map interactions. Modifying this collection changes the interactions associated with the map.`

Comment: I've found clearing all the interactions then adding the ones you want back in to be stable.

To remove all the interactions you can run `map.getInteractions().clear()`.

To add the interactions back in you can use the `defaultInteractions({}).extend([]).forEach(interaction => map.addInteraction(interaction))` configuring defaultInteractions and extend accordingly.

Comment: @Elliot This is clearly the most stable way. I was looking for a way to reset to defaults, thank you